# GNOME Disks and compress images

Tags: partitioning, disk-image, gnome-disk-utility

How can I create compressed images with GNOME Disks?
If it is not possible, what do you suggest instead?

Comment: I cannot mount ftp server and write images with clonezilla
https://sourceforge.net/p/clonezilla/discussion/Open_discussion/thread/3e0b1dfd/

Comment: Are you transferring with FTP over SSH?

Comment: succeeded to connect with clonezilla to sftp server. (FTP over ssh). I also need to restore to smaller partition. already try with clonezilla with the option that will not check the size of destination and it doesn't work.

Comment: I look for rsync, and i didn't figure it out. Is rsync can create compress image file and restore from them?

Comment: I already found a tool. It call fsarchiver. I found also a nice version with gui that call qt5-fsarchiver. you can look at my question and answer and vote for that